# Cannot update software, cannot install anything, cannot upgrade

Tags: upgrade, updates, software-center, package-management

I cannot update anything in my system. I use the terminal and this is what I get.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package libnepomukutils4 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Then I download `libnepomukutils4` and try to install it but then I get this error

> This is a major failure of your software management system. Please
>   check for broken packager with synaptic, check the file permissions
>   and correctness of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and reload the
>   software information with: `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get
>   update -f`

So I open synaptic and do what it's asking me to do but I can't get past this error

```
The following errors occured
E: The package libnepomukutils4 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
E: Internal error opening cache (1). Please report.
```

Contents of /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Lubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140416.2)]/ trusty main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution. deb http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted deb-src
http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution. deb http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted deb-src http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/
trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team. deb http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty universe deb-src
http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty universe deb
http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe deb-src
http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team. deb http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse deb-src http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty
multiverse deb http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-updates
multiverse deb-src http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-updates
multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team. deb http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted
universe multiverse deb-src http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/
trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-security main
restricted deb http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-security
universe deb-src http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-security
universe deb http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-security
multiverse deb-src http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-security
multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software. deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: What Ubuntu version is this?

Comment: 14.04 recent install

Comment: Edit your question and add in the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: need 10 rep score to post more than two links. I used nano becoz the command alone produces permission denied error.

Comment: Either post it to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ or change the ext so that they aren't links (like adding a space in `http`).

Comment: OK there you go.  http://paste.ubuntu.com/7970363/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` is incorrectly formatted. Delete everything in the file, and paste in the following:

```
# deb cdrom:[Lubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140416.2)]/ trusty main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.telepoint.bg/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Then, run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install -f`.